# xero's PayrollAuApi not working while AccoutingApi working fine

Tags: laravel, xero-api

I am working in laravel and trying to push employees data to Xero but it gives me error 401 saying,

> [401] Client error: `POST [https://api.xero.com/payroll.xro/2.0/Employees\`](https://api.xero.com/payroll.xro/2.0/Employees%5C%60) resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"Type":null,"Title":"Unauthorized","Status":401,"Detail":"AuthorizationUnsuccessful","Instance":"d283e208-b86a-4739-a18 (truncated...)

I have done configuration correctly because my AccountingApi is working fine.
Have a look on working code:

```
public function getAllTaxTypes(OauthCredentialManager $xeroCredentials){
    $apiInstance = resolve(\XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Api\AccountingApi::class);
    $taxTypes = $apiInstance->getTaxRates($xeroCredentials->getTenantId());
    dd($taxTypes);
}
```

It prints the `taxtypes` as expected, but why does it give me the error when I try to create employee on xero like this:

```
public function createEmployee(OauthCredentialManager $xeroCredentials){

    // Employee
    $apiInstance = resolve(\XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Api\PayrollUkApi::class);
    // $apiInstance = resolve(\XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Api\AccountingApi::class);
    $xeroTenantId =  $xeroCredentials->getTenantId();

    $employee = new Employee();
    $employee->setFirstName('jhon');
    $employee->setLastName('doe');

    $response = $apiInstance->createEmployee($xeroTenantId,$employee);
    dd($response);

   
}
```

Comment: @Brian Tompsett ! These are not the anwers I am looking for. My problem is with Roles and permissions on Xero related to the Payroll api.

Answer (score 0):

I finally, found the problem. Appropriate scopes were not added in the scope list in config file.
Each Api has different scopes needed to be enabled to access that particular endpoints.
You can see scopes here `https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/scopes/`
and add them in  `config/xero.php`